# Magento "Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on boolean"

Tags: php, apache, magento

Because what I found similar is a little different from the path.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on boolean in /MagentoProject/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php on line 71
```

The code that error message says is that line :

```
    $namespace .= '_' . (Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsite()->getCode());
```

How could I solve this? I didn't do anything...

I set the environment

1. brew install redis
2. brew install homebrew/php/php56 homebrew/php/php56-mcrypt homebrew/php/php56-opcache homebrew/php/php56-redis
3. Set virtual host
4. 'ln -s ../sites-available/linkshops2 .'

### Update

The point of error is below **function __construct()**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $namespace = 'customer';
    if ($this->getCustomerConfigShare()->isWebsiteScope()) {
        $namespace .= '_' . (Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsite()->getCode());
    }

$this->init($namespace);
Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_session_init', array('customer_session'=>$this));
}
```

Comment: Could you var_dump `Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsite()` ?

Comment: @WilliamJanoti After what you told me, I got an error with this link : http://kyungmoon.kr/static/51c813892c6c3abdb41c9409d64603241450956768513.png

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too when I use Magento 1.6 from an existing project.

And I created a file "local.xml" before installation under app/etc/ according to local.xml.template in the same folder. It no longer went through the installation progress but the site was successfully loaded.